# Why every value I am putting into List using Insert keyword has a data type String

Tags: python-3.x, list

"""
Why every value I am putting into List using Insert keyword has a data type String. Also inserted vale index -1 but the list is not arranged like that.

Please go through the Image Description
"""

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I10K.png)

```py
lis = []
def takeinput():
    x = int(input("Enter how many element you want to put into list"))
    while x != 0:
        lis.insert(-1,input())
        x = x-1
    return lis
takeinput()
type(lis[0])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: what out put you are exactly expecting

Comment: I am expecting a list which contains values of every data type when I am inserting using Insert keyword

Answer (score 0):

insert doesn't change the datatype of what it inserts into the list. Integer remains integer, strings remain strings:

```py
>>> lis = [1,2,3,4]
>>> lis.insert(-1, 5)
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```

As you see above, your new value is at the second last index of the list.
I think that is unwanted.

Normally you would use append instead of insert to fill an array.

```py
lis = []
new_var = 'foo'
if new_var not in lis:
    lis.append(new_var)
# ['foo']
```

You store strings into the list because with

```py
lis.insert(-1,input())
```

you insert the string of input() at the last element of your list.
input() ever gives a string.

If you want to have another datatype stored, you need to cast your input into this datatype before storing into your list.

```py
lis = []
def takeinput():
    x = int(input("Enter how many element you want to put into list"))
    while x != 0:
        new_item = input()  # store input string
        new_item = int(new_item)  # cast it to int for example
        lis.append(new_item)  # append it to the list
        x = x-1
    return lis
takeinput()
type(lis[0])
```

In python you can store **everything** into lists.

Comment: just copy my code and check the output, the data type of each value is string and  not int

Comment: And yeah we do use append and extend to insert values but what is the problem using Insert keyword?

Comment: If you want to have all new added items of the list as second last and the first added as last item you have to use insert. I was only thinking that would be a failure.

Comment: Did you read my post?  Of course is in your example each item in the list a string because you store them as string.